# Can anything be said about the independence of U, V and W if P(U) = 1 and P(V) = 1?

Tags: probability, independence

We have a probability space ($\Omega, F, P$) and we have events U, V, W where P(U) = 1 and P(V) = 1. Can anything be said about the independence of U, V and W?

I was thinking that P(U) = 1 = P($\Omega$) and P(V) = 1 = P($\Omega$)

U = $\Omega$ and V = $\Omega$

P(U $\cap$ V) = P($\Omega$ $\cap$ $\Omega$) = 1 = P(U)*P(V) so U and V are independent

P(U $\cap$ W) = P($\Omega$ $\cap$ W) = P(W) = P(U)*P(W) so U and W are independent

P(V $\cap$ W) = P($\Omega$ $\cap$ W) = P(W) = P(V)*P(W) so V and W are independent

P(U $\cap$ V $\cap$ W) = P($\Omega$ $\cap$ $\Omega$ $\cap$ W) = P(W) = P(U)*P(V)*P(W)

Using all that, U, V and W are independent

Is that what can be said about U, V and W's independence?

Comment: $\Pr(U)=1=\Pr(\Omega)$ does *not* imply that $U=\Omega$.  All it implies is that $U^c$ is a [null-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set), i.e. that $\Pr(U^c)=0$.  The empty set is an example of a null-set but it is far from the only example.

Comment: By inclusion-exclusion $\Pr(U\cap V) = \Pr(U)+\Pr(V)-\Pr(U\cup V)$.  Now, $\Pr(U\cup V)\geq \Pr(U)=1$ since $U\cup V\supseteq U$ and $\Pr(U\cup V)\leq 1$ since it is a probability... hence $\Pr(U\cap V)=1+1-1=1$.  Do similar with the others.

Comment: Alternatively, note that $\Pr(V) = \Pr(U\cap V)+\Pr(U^c\cap V)$ and use that $U^c$ is a nullset and subsets of nullsets are also nullsets, again emphasizing the difference in terminology that nullset is not a synonym for empty set.

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense. I was able to prove their mutual independence that way